# Enable WS Security Authentication in SOAP UI mockService

Tags: web-services, authentication, soapui, ws-security

I am trying to create a mockWebservice which should Authenticate UserName,password sent in the SOAP Request xml header.

My request xml will look like this

```
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s11:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>User_Name</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
      <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">DeliverAccountInvestigationCaseStatus</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">http://rp.baml.com</wsa:To>
      <wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">Test from APP_NAME</wsa:MessageID>
   </s11:Header>
   <s11:Body>
      <tns:DeliverAccountInvestigationCaseStatusRequest xsi:schemaLocation="http://rp.baml.com/data/DeliverAccountInvestigationCaseStatusV001 DeliverAccountInvestigationCaseStatusV001.xsd" xmlns:tns="http://rp.baml.com/data/DeliverAccountInvestigationCaseStatusV001" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <tns:ReferenceNumber type="GSS">1-</tns:ReferenceNumber>
         <tns:TimeStamp>2014-01-31</tns:TimeStamp>
         <tns:Status></tns:Status>
         <tns:Resolution></tns:Resolution>
         <tns:Comment>Test</tns:Comment>
      </tns:DeliverAccountInvestigationCaseStatusRequest>
   </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
```

My Webservice should throw error if, username or password is not correct in the header.

Comment: What is your question? What did you do try to meet the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

When you mock a response you are simulating a response to a service's request. You normally mock when you cannot reach one of the supporting web services or it has not yet been built.

What this means is that you can mock any kind of response. If you need to validate the username and password, you will have to write that validation code yourself.

Check out soapUI.org's [service mocking guide](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/concept.html) for some background on mocking.